# How to Whitelist a Container using the Open Policy Agent Gatekeeper K8sPSPCapabilities Constraint Template

Tags: open-policy-agent

I'd like to whitelist a container in the K8sPSPCapabilities constraint template but am having some difficulty with the rego language.  I'd like to disallow the NET_RAW capability for all containers except a specific container.  Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're referring to [this template](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/library/pod-security-policy/capabilities/template.yaml) from the Gatekeeper ConstraintTemplate library, which is daunting. Unfortunately as written that ConstraintTemplate doesn't allow deny listing specific `allowedCapabilities`. Let's construct it.

If you're just looking for the Rego, [here's it in the Rego Playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/axFzY0YI3X).

**Validating a Container**

We'll start from the inside out. First, let's assume we have a Container and want to ensure it does not have `NET_RAW` in `.securityContext.capabilities.add`. First, we'll collect the values of this list into a set.

```
capabilities := {c | c := container.securityContext.capabilities.add[_]}
```

This is called a [set comprehension](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#set-comprehensions).

Since it's quite possible that you'll want to deny multiple capabilities, we'll assume you'll want to set this as a list parameter rather than having it hard-coded in your ConstraintTemplate. We need to convert this list from `input.parameters` into a set as well.

```
denied := {c | c := input.parameters.deniedCapabilities[_]}
```

What we want to do now is construct the [set intersection](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#sets-2) between the `capabilities` in the Container and those in `denied`.

```
count(capabilities & denied) > 0
```

This returns `true` if there are any capabilities in both the container and in the list of denied capabilities.

We must consider the case where the Container specifies `'*'`, which would implicitly include `NET_RAW` but not be matched by our logic above. We check this case with:

```
capabilities['*']
```

Note that every truthy statement in a Rego function is implicitly AND-ed together. So the following would check both conditions, but we want to match either:

```
count(capabilities & denied) > 0
capabilities['*']
```

We can do this by providing *two* definitions for `has_disallowed_capabilities`:

```
has_disallowed_capabilities(container) {
    capabilities := {c | c := container.securityContext.capabilities.add[_]}
    denied := {c | c := input.parameters.deniedCapabilities[_]}
    count(capabilities & denied) > 0
}

has_disallowed_capabilities(container) {
    capabilities := {c | c := container.securityContext.capabilities.add[_]}
    capabilities["*"]
}
```

If we call `has_disallowed_capabilities` on a Container, Rego will automatically check both definitions and return true if *at least one* returns true.

**Validating a Pod**

Now we'll actually write the `violation` functions idiomatic to Gatekeeper.

```
violation[{"msg": msg}] {
    container := input.review.object.spec.containers[_]
    has_disallowed_capabilities(container)
    msg := sprintf("container <%v> has a disallowed capability. Denied capabilities are %v", [container.name, input.parameters.deniedCapabilities])
}
```

This violation first creates an [iterator](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#arrays-1), `container`, which will iterate over all Containers in the Pod. By calling a function on the iterator, we implicitly call that function on *every* Container in the iterator.

We must also check `initContainers` as those may also have the `NET_RAW` capability. It looks near-identical to the above:

```
violation[{"msg": msg}] {
    container := input.review.object.spec.initContainers[_]
    has_disallowed_capabilities(container)
    msg := sprintf("initContainer <%v> has a disallowed capability. Denied capabilities are %v", [container.name, input.parameters.deniedCapabilities])
}
```

**Whitelisting a Container**

Almost done. As you said above, we want to whitelist a specific container. Recall that all statements in a Rego function are AND-ed together, and the `violation` function must return `true` in order for the Container to fail validation. So if we create a statement that evaluates to `false` if it matches the Container we want, we're done!

Let's say we want to ignore Containers with the `name: abc`. We can match all other containers with:

```
container.name != "abc"
```

This just needs to go in both of our `violation` functions, and we'll be all set!

**Putting everything together**

Finally, we put all that we've created above into a ConstraintTemplate:

```
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: ConstraintTemplate
metadata:
  name: k8spspdeniedcapabilities
  annotations:
    description: Denies Pod capabilities.
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: K8sPSPDeniedCapabilities
      validation:
        # Schema for the `parameters` field
        openAPIV3Schema:
          properties:
            deniedCapabilities:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package capabilities
        
        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
            container := input.review.object.spec.containers[_]
            container.name != "abc"
            has_disallowed_capabilities(container)
            msg := sprintf("container <%v> has a disallowed capability. Denied capabilities are %v", [container.name, input.parameters.deniedCapabilities])
        }
        
        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
            container := input.review.object.spec.initContainers[_]
            container.name != "abc"
            has_disallowed_capabilities(container)
            msg := sprintf("initContainer <%v> has a disallowed capability. Denied capabilities are %v", [container.name, input.parameters.deniedCapabilities])
        }
        
        has_disallowed_capabilities(container) {
            capabilities := {c | c := container.securityContext.capabilities.add[_]}
            denied := {c | c := input.parameters.deniedCapabilities[_]}
            count(capabilities & denied) > 0
        }
        
        has_disallowed_capabilities(container) {
            capabilities := {c | c := container.securityContext.capabilities.add[_]}
            capabilities["*"]
        }
```

And a Constraint to instantiate it:

```
apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: K8sPSPDeniedCapabilities
metadata:
  name: denied-capabilities
spec:
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        kinds: ["Pod"]
  parameters:
    deniedCapabilities: ["NET_RAW"]
```

If instead you want the whitelisted containers to be configurable, you would follow a similar process to the one we used to make `deniedCapabilities`.